# Task is not being scheduled as expected in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Here's the hello-world dag python file defined:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 10, 23, 11, 25),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('test_jason_1', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@daily")

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='echo "123" && exit 1',
    dag=dag)
```

Current datetime from command line (same machine as where Airflow is installed) is:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-XXX print_date]$ date
Mon Oct 23 11:24:56 UTC 2017
```

but after 11:25:00, this job is still not scheduled accordingly. Could anyone help correct me if i'm wrong? Thanks!

**P.S.** I changed `schedule_interval` to `timedelta(minutes=5)`, and current time is `2017-10-23 12:36`, then I could see the logs' time as in the right, which is confusing. Any explanations?

[image]

Comment: Have you check this page: https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html, make sure you understand the trigger time is `start_date + scheduler_interval`

Comment: @Chengzhi I tried to set `'start_date': datetime(2017, 10, 22, 17, 15),` and `schedule_interval="@daily"` at time 2017-10-23 17:10:00, but even after 17:16, this task is still not scheduled as expected. As per the formula `start_date + scheduler_interval`, the next running time should be 2017-10-23 17:15:00, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Chengzhi after setting as above, I could see the following info from "task instance details" subpage in UI: ```schedule_interval: 1 day, 0:00:00; 
start_date: 2017-10-22 17:02:00```

Comment: I think @daily means Run once a day at midnight UTC (the cron looks like this `0 0 * * *`) according to here: https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html. I think it overrides your time somehow. You might need to use something like `*/15 * * * *` if you want to run every 15 minutes

Comment: @Chengzhi how bout run it daily at 12:45pm, provided that current datetime is 2017-10-24 12:35pm. I expect to see it scheduling at "2017-10-24 12:45pm" (which means including today for testing), "2017-10-25 12:45pm", "2017-10-25 12:45pm", ...

Comment: You don't need to provide the detail time as start_date,  so I would do 'start_date': datetime(2017, 10, 23), then for schedule_interval use the crontab like `45 12 * * *`

Comment: @Chengzhi I see, thanks bro, i'll have a try then